# Trying to understand the implementation of delegates with protocols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, delegates

After doing loads of research I am still a little confused about how to use and implement delegates. I have tried writing my own, simplified example, to aid my understanding - however it does not working - meaning I must be a little lost.

```
//the underlying protocol
protocol myRules {
    func sayName(name: String);
}

//the delegate that explains the protocols job
class myRulesDelegate: myRules {
    func sayName(name: String){
        print(name);
    }
}

//the delegator that wants to use the delegate
class Person{
    //the delegator telling which delegate to use
    weak var delegate: myRulesDelegate!;
    var myName: String!;

    init(name: String){
        self.myName = name;
    }
    func useDels(){
        //using the delegate (this causes error)
        delegate?.sayName(myName);
    }
}

var obj =  Person(name: "Tom");
obj.useDels();
```

I have read and watched so many tutorials but am still struggling. I no longer get error (cheers guys). But still get no output from sayName.

which demonstrates I must be misunderstanding how delegate patterns work.
I would really appreciate a corrected version of the code, with a simple explanation as to why it works, and why it is helpful.

I hope this helps others too. Cheers.

Comment: You forgot to assign the delegate before using it. Like `obj.delegate = myRulesDelegate()`. And since it's an implicitly unwrapped optional, it crashes. See Paulw11's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you omit the first parameter's external name, so your function call should be `delegate.sayName("Tom")`

Also, it is dangerous to use an implicitly unwrapped optional for your `delegate` property, as you have found.  You should use a weak optional:

```
//the underlying protocol
protocol MyRulesDelegate: class {
    func sayName(name: String)
}

//the delegator that wants to use the delegate
class Person {
    //the delegator referencing the delegate to use
    weak var delegate: MyRulesDelegate?
    var myName: String

    init(name: String){
        self.myName = name
    }

    func useDels() {
        //using the delegate
        delegate?.sayName(myName)
    }
}
```

Finally, your delegate must be an object, so you can't use a delegate in the way you have shown; you need to create another class that can set an instance of itself as the delegate

```
class SomeOtherClass: MyRulesDelegate {

    var myPerson: Person

    init() {
        self.myPerson = Person(name:"Tom")
        self.myPerson.delegate = self
    }

    func sayName(name: String) {
        print("In the delegate function, the name is \(name)")
    }
}


var something = SomeOtherClass()
something.myPerson.useDels()
```

Output:

> **In the delegate function, the name is Tom**

Comment: corrected - still an issue - check update. Huge thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I had a cut & paste error where I still include the `name` parameter name